# Error while building after update Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just installed the Google Repository as I wanted to use ads in my app. Also added the `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'` in the build.gradle file. After that as soon I clicked on the Gradle sync button I had a lot of errors and my build failed. Here is the list of errors.

```
C:\Users\Samarth Agarwal\AndroidStudioProjects\HTTPRequest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v11\values.xml
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Samarth Agarwal\AndroidStudioProjects\HTTPRequest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v14\values.xml
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
Error:(9, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
C:\Users\Samarth Agarwal\AndroidStudioProjects\HTTPRequest\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v21\values.xml
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
```

and similar 101 errors. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced a similar issue while modifying the build.gradle
I found another way to add the Google play as a dependency and this worked fine for me.

Go to File -> Project Structure -> Select Project Settings -> Select 'Dependencies' Tab Click '+' -> 1.Library Dependencies -> Select com.google.android.gms:play-services:+